# Attach behavior to Items in GridView

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, attachedbehaviors

I've got a ListView with a GridView used to present Items. ListView is defined like

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding ...}>
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn>...</GridViewColumn>
         <GridViewColumn>...</GridViewColumn>
         <GridViewColumn>...</GridViewColumn>
         ...
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

How can I attach custom behavior to each Item in the List (one behavior for all items)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of behaviour you would like to have? Something like Underline when hovered over?

Comment: its drag'n'drop behavior

Comment: [WPF Drag and drop - using MvvM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/420545/WPF-Drag-and-Drop-MVVM-using-Behavior)